# Is there a way Hasura can generate tables automatically using a schema.graphql file similar to keystonejs?

Tags: graphql, keystonejs, hasura

I'm wondering if there's a way where if given a schema.graphql file Hasura can create the required tables for the GraphQL endpoint? I'm looking for something similar to what keystonejs provides.

My current understanding is

Hasura
Tables --> GraphQL

KeystoneJS
Schema --> GraphQL (With automatic creation of tables)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `graphql-to-sql`, here's an example (click "run"):

https://repl.it/repls/DangerousOutlyingSolution#index.js

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything about seeding or migrating in existing GraphQL file.

Maybe because they only operate on a PostgreSQL DB? You can just go a little more [low level and seed the underlying PostgreSQL DB with some DDL](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/migrations/advanced/seed-data-migration.html#seed-data-migration).